# Uniqueness of solution for second order Volterra equaiton

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, solution-verification

Let $g, h:[0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous, $h$ bounded in $[0, \infty)$. Show that if

$$y(x)=g(x)+\int_{0}^{x} h(x-\tau)y(\tau)d \tau,\text{ } x \geq 0$$

has a continuous solution in $[0, \infty)$, then it is unique.

Consider

$$y_{i}(x)=g(x)+\int_{0}^{x}f(x,\tau,y_{i}(\tau))d\tau,\text{ }x\geq0,\text{ }i=1,2,$$

$f(x,\tau,y(\tau))=h(x-\tau)y(\tau)$.

If $u(x)=\left|y_{1}(x)-y_{2}(x)\right|$,

$$\left|f(x,\tau,y_{1}(x))-f(x,\tau,y_{2}(x))\right|\leq k(x,\tau,u(x)).$$

Note $k$ is Lipschitz continuous. Then,

$$0\leq u(x)\leq \int_{0}^{x}k(\tau,x,u(\tau))d\tau,\text{ }x\geq0.$$

After that I get stuck. I know I have to use Gronwall's inequality, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.

Since $h$ is bounded, there exists $M>0$ such that $|h(x)|\leq M$ for all $x$. Since $f(x,\tau,y(\tau))=h(x-\tau)y(\tau)$,
$$\left|f(x,\tau,y_{1}(x))-f(x,\tau,y_{2}(x))\right|\leq |h(x-\tau)||y_1(x)-y_2(x)|\leq M u(x).$$
So
$$0\leq u(x)\leq M\int_{0}^{x}u(\tau)d\tau,\qquad x\geq0.$$
Now classical Gronwall's inequality tells that $u\equiv 0$: Write $U(x)=\int_{0}^{x}u(\tau)d\tau$ then $U$ is differentiable with $U'(x)\leq M U(x)$, i.e., $(e^{-Mx}U)'\leq 0$, so $e^{-Mx}U(x)$ is non-increasing. Since $U(0)=0$ and $U\ge 0$, $U\equiv0$, and then $u\equiv0$.